# Materialize Common Table Expression in HANA

Tags: hana

Is there a way to force HANA to materialize a subquery in a WITH clause like what  MATERIALIZE and INLINE optimizer hints do as below in Oracle?

```
WITH dept_count AS (
  SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */ deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
  FROM   emp
  GROUP BY deptno)
SELECT ...
```

I find no such hint in hana.  Any help?

Comment: Why do you think you need that? With HANA being an in-memory database, materializing (=storing the result on disk) is most probably going to be slower than processing the data in memory. Even in Oracle, more often than not, this makes the query slower, rather than faster.

Comment: I had a complex query,and I analyse the execution plan,found that the result of the common table expression does not get materialized,so that the query is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

For SAP HANA *materializing* an intermediate result set usually is not improving performance; on the contrary, SAP HANA strives to materialize as late as possible, so that it can process the data in its more compact internal representation.

What you probably like to see is that common table expressions, that are used at multiple places in your query, don't get re-executed for every reference.

This optimisation is called **"subplan sharing"** in SAP HANA and active by default.

Looking at an `EXPLAIN PLAN` output can verify if a query uses "subplan sharing":

```
OPERATOR_NAME                       OPERATOR_DETAILS
                                                       ...
ROW SEARCH                          KF_MED.MKF1, KF_MED.MKF2, KF_DAT.MKF1, 

[...]
      COLUMN SEARCH                 KF_MED.MKF1, KF_MED.MKF2, FACT.KF1, FACT.KF2                               ...
        FILTER                      FACT.KF2 <> KF_MED.MKF2 OR KF_MED.MKF2 IS NULL OR FACT.KF2 IS NULL         ...
          JOIN                      JOIN CONDITION: (INNER many-to-one) FACT.KF1 = KF_MED.MKF1                 ...
            COLUMN TABLE                                                                                       ...
            ROW SEARCH              KF_MED.MKF1, KF_MED.MKF2                                                   ...
              VIEW                  PROJECT COLS: KF_MED.MKF1, KF_MED.MKF2,                                    ...
   ===>        (SHARED SUBPLAN)     SUBPLAN OPERATOR_ID : 9                                                     ...
    VIEW                            PROJECT COLS: KF_MED.MKF1, KF_MED.MKF2,                                    ...
   ===>  (SHARED SUBPLAN)           SUBPLAN OPERATOR_ID : 9
```

See the two line marked with `===>` above.

In case the optimizer does not choose to use "subplan sharing" you may try and use a hint to indicate that this is the desired behaviour:

```
 SELECT * FROM T1 WITH HINT( SUBPLAN_SHARING );
```

However, before trying to "force" the optimizer to do anything, make sure to understand what is currently happening. Hints are technical debt in your code and should be avoided if possible.